Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka Client triggers 'mutating configuration' deprecation warnings in Gradle 8.11.1
Description:
I'm in the process of upgrading my project to Gradle 8.11.1 and have started seeing deprecation warnings like this:
Mutating the dependency attributes of configuration ':compileOnly' after it has been resolved or consumed. This behavior has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 9.0. After a Configuration has been resolved, consumed as a variant, or used for generating published metadata, it should not be modified. 
Mutating the dependency attributes of configuration ':implementation' after it has been resolved or consumed. This behavior has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 9.0. After a Configuration has been resolved, consumed as a variant, or used for generating published metadata, it should not be modified.
After some analysis  I’ve pinpointed that these warnings appear when I include the following dependency:
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
When I comment out the Eureka client starter, the warnings disappear. I’m currently using:

Spring Boot: 3.2.5
Spring Cloud Dependencies BOM: 2023.0.1

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there known workarounds, specific versions, or configurations to avoid these warnings, especially with Spring Cloud Eureka and Gradle 8.11.1?
